# Javascript: Run async task in series(or sequence) without libraries

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I want to run some asynchronous task in a loop, but it should execute in sequence order(one after another). It should be vanilla JS, not with any libraries.

```
var doSome = function(i) {
   return Promise.resolve(setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done... ' + i)
   }, 1000 * (i%3)));
}

var looper = function() {
   var p = Promise.resolve();

   [1,2,3].forEach((n) => {
      p = p.then(() => doSome(n))
   })

   return p;
}

looper();
```

**Current output:**

```
calling for ...1
calling for ...2
calling for ...3
Promise {<resolved>: 8260}
done... 3
done... 1
done... 2
```

**Expected output:**

```
calling for ...1
calling for ...2
calling for ...3
Promise {<resolved>: 8260}
done... 1
done... 2
done... 3
```

Note: Kindly answer, if you tried and it's working as expected

Comment: The only reason the code is executing in the order 3, 1, 2 is that your modulus math is wrong.  `1%3=1`, `2%3=2` but `3%3=0`, so for 1 it is waiting 1000ms, 2 it is waiting 2000ms, but for 3 it is waiting 0ms.

Comment: Perhaps relevant here: [How to synchronize a sequence of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506) and [ES6 promises async each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028552/es6-promises-something-like-async-each/32028826#32028826) and [Make .forEach() wait before going onto the next iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983424/make-angular-foreach-wait-for-promise-after-going-to-next-object/28983668#28983668)

Comment: `Promise.resolve(setTimeout(` wut... you realize that resolves immediately with a number, and therefore doesn't wait on the timeout, right?

Comment: I don't see where in your code the `calling for ...` is logged?

Comment: @KevinB - the code as posed in the question is not quite achieving what the user intends, I don't believe.  The first snippet in my answer below I think is a clearer representation of what the user is trying to describe.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Maybe so, but i'd rather the op clarify the question. If that promise was created correctly, the code would otherwise work as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from your comment below, I think your own example code isn't quite matching your description.  I think what you want for your example is something closer to the below snippet:

```js
var doSome = function(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`Completing ${i}`), 1000*(i%3))
  });
}

var looper = function() {
  [1,2,3].forEach((n) => {
    doSome(n).then(console.log);
  });
}

looper();
```

Here, the array `[1, 2, 3]` is iterated over, and an asynchronous process is generated for each one.  As each of those async processes complete, we `.then` on them and console log their resolved result.

**So**, now the question comes how to best queue the results?  Below, I stored them into an array, then leveraged [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in order to pause execution on the results until they complete *in order*.

```js
// This is probably what you want
var doSome = function(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`Completing ${i}`), 1000*(i%3))
  });
}

var looper = async function() {
  const nums = [1,2,3];
  const promises = []
  nums.forEach((n) => {
    console.log(`Queueing ${n}`);
    promises.push(doSome(n));
  });
  for (let promise of promises) {
    const result = await promise;
    console.log(result);
  }
}

looper();
```

Now, we *could* have eliminated a loop and only executed one after the last completed:

```js
// Don't use this-- it is less efficient
var doSome = function(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`Completing ${i}`), 1000*(i%3))
  });
}

var looper = async function() {
  const nums = [1,2,3];
  const promises = [];
  for (let n of nums) {
    console.log(`Queueing ${n}`);
    const result = await doSome(n);
    console.log(result);
  };
}

looper();
```

But, as you can see in the log, this approach won't queue up the next async process until the previous one has completed.  This is undesirable and doesn't match your use case.  What we get from the two-looped approach preceding this one is that all async processes are immediately executed, but then we order/queue the results so they respect our predefined order, not the order in which they resolve.

### UPDATE

Regarding `Promise.all`, `async`/`await` and the intended behavior of the queueing:

So, if you want to avoid using `async`/`await`, I think you could write some sort of utility:

```js
var doSome = function(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`Completing ${i}`), 1000*(i%3))
  });
}

function handlePromiseQueue(queue) {
  let promise = queue.shift();
  promise.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      handlePromiseQueue(queue);
    }
  })
}

var looper = function() {
  const nums = [1,2,3];
  const promises = []
  nums.forEach((n) => {
    console.log(`Queueing ${n}`);
    promises.push(doSome(n));
  });
  handlePromiseQueue(promises);
}

looper();
```

**HOWEVER**, let me be clear-- if user [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s assertion is correct, and it is *not* important that each async promise be executed upon as soon as it resolves, only that none of them be acted upon until they *all* have come back, then this can 100% be simplified with `Promise.all`:

```js
// This is probably what you want
var doSome = function(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(`Completing ${i}`), 1000*(i%3))
  });
}

function handlePromiseQueue(queue) {
  let promise = queue.shift();
  promise.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      handlePromiseQueue(queue);
    }
  })
}

var looper = function() {
  const nums = [1,2,3];
  const promises = []
  nums.forEach((n) => {
    console.log(`Queueing ${n}`);
    promises.push(doSome(n));
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => handlePromiseQueue(promises));
}

looper();
```

Finally, as Bergi also pointed out, I am playing fast and loose here by not setting up any [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) on these various promises-- I omitted them for brevity in examples, but for your purposes you will want to include proper handling for errors or bad requests.

Comment: It's not  by mistake I did so, I intentionally want to mimic that the last task is short task compared to the others. Even the task is small, it should run in the sequence. That's my use case. 

Tasks of varying execution time should be run in the called sequence. This is my use case.

You don't even have to correct this one, just give a new example.

Comment: @KamalakannanJ - OK, let me make sure I understand your use case then.  You have three async processes that will kick off simultaneously, but you then want to make sure that each of their callbacks/`.then` functions execute in a specific order regardless of the order in which the async processes resolve?

Comment: You're right @Alexander. It will be kicked off from a for-loop and it should be executed in the same order after one another.

Comment: @KamalakannanJ - I've updated based on your comments and my new understanding of your requirements.  Please review and if it fulfills your needs mark it as the selected answer.  If not, please comment to explain how this fails to meet your needs.

Comment: Your second snippet is dangerous, [don't create multiple promises and sequentially `await` them but use `Promise.all` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation)!

Comment: @Bergi - the problem is that he doesn't want to do _one_ thing after _all_ promises complete, he wants to fire off all asyncs at once, but queue each of their callbacks in a specific order and fire each one as soon as possible.  I see the risk with "what if one fails", but a `catch` that broke the loop could probably mitigate that, no?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I don't see where you got "as soon as possible" from, imo `for (const result of await Promise.all(promises)) console.log(result);` is enough and has the expected output. If you want to use your approach, yes, you will need to explicitly `.catch` errors (and if only to ignore them) of all promises that you create without immediately awaiting them.

Comment: @Bergi - I inferred it from the text "execute in sequence order(one after another)" and from the manner in which the user seems to be coding it to execute as quickly as possible.  I 100% agree with you that, if I am interpreting his intent incorrectly, and he just wants to wait until they all complete and then start executing responses in order, then `Promise.all` is of course the cleaner, safer, more expressive approach.

Comment: @AlexanderNied It's working as Expected. Thanks. Just one doubt, is there any way to do without `async/await` ?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not getting the expected results with `Promise.all`, because all the promises are triggered simultaneously, so the 3rd promise(which has 0ms as timeout) ran first.

Comment: @KamalakannanJ - I have updated the answer with a solution that avoids `async`/`await`, as well as a solution that works with `Promise.all`.  I would recommend you pay careful attention to the latter, as it is the cleanest option _**if**_ it meets your requirements.  Good luck!

Comment: Both of the new solutions work, but I'm confused with how the latter works. Because, in both you're calling `handlePromiseQueue`, so does the promises execute twice in latter ?

Comment: @KamalakannanJ - `handlePromiseQueue` is a [recursive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) stand-in for a while loop-- each it runs, it evaluates the array, shifts the first promise off the array and `.then`s it, and when it is done it re-calls itself with the same array.  Once there are no items left in the array it exits.  In the `Promise.all` example, we simply wait until all the promises have resolved before we start calling `.then` on them, whereas in the previous example we start `.then`ing them as soon as they are resolved and next in the queue.